# ionic 3 Firestore Add and Update Function Error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update some data in Firebase but it is giving me the following error:

> ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with
>   invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field id)

I am adding and editing data from same page. Logic is if the id of data is matched then it will open edit and if its not same then its adding.
Adding is working fine. But in edit data it is showing the above error.

Can anyone provide assistance or give a hint so that I can resolve this issue. Thanks

```
if (this.navParams.data.deal) {
  this.title = "EDIT DEAL";
  this.buttonText = "Update";
  this.deal = this.navParams.data.deal;
  this.dealForm = fb.group({
    'name': [this.deal.name, [Validators.required]],
    'city': [this.deal.city],
    'number': [this.deal.number],
    'gender': [this.deal.gender],
    'birthday': [this.deal.birthday],
            'userId': [''],
    'userName': [''],
    'id':[''],



    'isInvite':this.deal.isInvite|| false
  })

} else {
  this.deal = {
    approved: 'pending'
  }

  this.dealForm = fb.group({
    'name': ['', Validators.required],
    'city': ['', [Validators.required]],
    'number': ['', Validators.required],
    'gender': ['', Validators.required],
    'userName': [''],
    'userId': [''],
    'birthday': ['', [Validators.required]],
    'id':[''],


  })
}

 }


  submit() {
    if (!this.dealForm.valid) {
      this.helper.presentAlert('Error', 'please correct the data and retry 
      again', 'ok');
      return;
    }

let deal: Deal = {
  approved: 'pending',
  name: this.dealForm.get('name').value,
  city: this.dealForm.get('city').value,
  birthday: this.dealForm.get('birthday').value,
  number: this.dealForm.get('number').value,
  gender: this.dealForm.get('gender').value,
       userId: this.user.uid,
  userName: this.user.name,
  id:'',


  photo: this.deal.photo || '',

  isInvite:false
}
console.log(this.deal.id);

this.helper.load();
if (this.navParams.data.deal) {
  deal.id = this.deal.id;
  console.log(deal.id);

  this.api.updateDeal(deal.id, deal).then(r => {
    console.log('deal id' + this.deal.id + ' updated successfully');
    this.helper.toast(`Updated Deal sent for approval from admin!`);
    this.navCtrl.pop().then(() => this.helper.dismiss());
  })
} else {

  this.api.addDeal(deal).then(resp => {
    console.log(resp);

    this.helper.toast(`Child Added ! . Thanks for using Medrec`);
    this.navCtrl.pop().then(() => this.helper.dismiss());
  });

}
```

}

api.ts

```
  updateDeal(id,data){
    return this.afs.doc('child/'+id).update(data);
  }
```

Comment: The error message is saying that the `id` field of the document data is undefined.

Comment: The `id` of the deal is undefined as @DougStevenson mentioned. You will need to update your code so that it will pass the `id` through to Firestore.